# I have a list with item in lists and I want to give them a name for each list python

Tags: python

I have a list with item in lists and I want to give them a name for each list I do not know how is the number of items in the list:

```
lists = [[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0]...]

#result:
0 = [1.0, 2.0]
1 = [3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0]
... = []

#I have this script but doesn’t work 


number_of_items = len(listas)
names = range(number_of_items)



for x in names:
    for i in listas:
        x = [i]



#any advice?
```

Comment: what name do you want to assign to ?

Comment: An identifier must start with a letter or underscore, **never** with a digit.  Therefore, in **no** way, shape, or form, is it **ever** going to be possible to use `0`, `1`, and so forth, as **names**.  You must reset your peculiar specs to either use those digits as (e.g) keys in a dictionary, rather than actual names (identifiers), or (more problematically, but technically feasible) accepts names with a letter or underscore prefix, e.g, `_0`, `_1`, and so forth.  If you deigned to explain what the flip you're trying to accomplish with this weird scheme it might be easier to help you!

Comment: I am trying to put each items in lists with a name for call it when I need them, but I am going to trying using a dictionary. Thank you for your advice and comments  @AlexMartelli

Comment: any name will be work @levi the thing is that I do not know the size of the list, for that reason I think can used numbers to the items. I am going to trying with a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put them all in a dictionary, e.g.:

```
lists = [[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0], [4,5,6]]


out_dict = {}
for i,l in enumerate(lists):
    out_dict[i] = l

print(out_dict)

# which gives
{0: [1.0, 2.0], 1: [3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0], 2: [4, 5, 6]}
```

But if you use 0,1,2 as keys/names, its like using your original list anyway.

Alternatively, you can add variables to the namespace as follows:

```
for i,l in enumerate(lists):
    locals()['v'+str(i)] = l


print(v0, v1, v2)
#[1.0, 2.0] [3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0] [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: You could also use dict comprehension `{i: l for i,l in enumerate(lists)}
`

Answer (score 0):

```
lists = [[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0]]
for x,i in zip(range(len(lists)),lists):
    print str(x) + " = " + str(i)
```

The `zip()` function used here is used to iterate over the two loops that you were using previously, simultaneously. This enabled the print of expected result.

Comment: thanks this was what I wanted to do : ) @code frenzy

Answer (score 0):

use a dictionary

```
>>> lm = {}
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = [4,5,6]
>>> l3 = [7,8,9]
>>> lm["l1"] = l1
>>> lm["l2"] = l2
>>> lm["l3"] = l3
>>> lm
{'l2': [4, 5, 6], 'l3': [7, 8, 9], 'l1': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> lm["l1"]
[1, 2, 3]
```